# How to import other script in same dir?

Tags: python, schedule

I am trying to put a few python scripts to scheduled and run in `main.py`. Those scripts are put in the same folder.

`main.py`:

```py
import schedule
import time
from test1 import dd

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(dd,fname)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

`test1.py`:

```
def dd(fname):
    print('hello' + fname)

dd('Mary')
dd('John')
```

It run out as those 2 name and  `name 'fname' is not defined`.

How to define the argument at `main.py` file? If I have more than one `def` in the script, shall I need to import multiple times in the `main.py`
and the script that I import at top of `main.py`, it run once before running the schedule? That mean it will run one while you import it?

Comment: `fname` is the only defined in the scope of the function when it is ran. Call the function with `dd("Mary")` or a variable, and then inside the function `fname` will be defined as whatever you passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not defining your fname in main.py so it says `name 'fname' is not defined`. You are only importing the functions to main.py from test1.py

Here is the modified code:
**main.py**

```
import schedule
import time
from test1 import dd

fname="Mary"
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(dd,fname)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**test1.py**

```
def dd(fname):
    print('hello' + fname)
```

if you want to input more than one string, just simply use a list! Here is the sample code for test1.py:

```
def dd(fname:list):
    for n in fname:
        print('hello' + n)
```

These codes are tested using Python 3.7.7

Comment: thanks for help, it works.
then how about the ```fname``` is a forloop function like looping the name

Comment: Well in this case I think you could just change the fname from a string to a list and iterate over it in your dd function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use a function argument as it's own variable. Importing is not the problem here.

Try this:

```py
import schedule
import time
from test1 import dd

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(dd,("Any String",))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```